# Alterar arquivo de configuração pelo configparser remove_section

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como salvo o arquivo de configuração (`.ini`) após realizar a exclusão de uma opção ou seção?

Estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

teste.ini

```
[LOCAL]
url = 'http://localhost:8080/'
username = 'usuario'
password = 'SECRET'

[TESTE]
url = 'http://localhost:8080/teste/'
username = 'usuario'
password = 'SECRET'
```

remove.py

```
import configparser

parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
parser.read('teste.ini')

print('Lendo Valores:')
for section in parser.sections():
    print(section)
    for name, value in parser.items(section):
        print(f"{name} = {value}")

parser.remove_option('LOCAL', 'password')
parser.remove_section('TESTE')

print('\Valor Modificado:')
for section in parser.sections():
    print(section)
    for name, value in parser.items(section):
        print(f"{name} = {value}")
```

Porém não consigo salvar a alteração, nos testes que fiz utilizando alguns exemplos que encontrei na internet o arquivo duplica algumas TAGS, salva apenas a metade do arquivo e às vezes nem salva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuei com os testes aqui e terminei misturando alguns exemplos que encontrei na internet, com isso consegui resolver o problema, não sei se foi a melhor forma de resolver o problema.

```
import configparser

parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
parser.read("teste.ini")

print('Lendo Valores:')
for section in parser.sections():
    print(section)
    for name, value in parser.items(section):
        print(f"{name} = {value}")

parser.remove_option('TESTE', 'password')
parser.remove_section('LOCAL')

with open("teste.ini", "w") as ArqTeste:
  parser.write(ArqTeste)
ArqTeste.close()

print('Valor Modificado:')
for section in parser.sections():
    print(section)
    for name, value in parser.items(section):
        print(f"{name} = {value}")
```

Como eu disse anteriormente, não sei se foi a melhor forma, mais foi a forma que consegui resolver o meu problema e dar continuidade no desenvolvimento...

Comment: Apenas um detalhe, você não precisa executar `ArqTeste.close()` pois o `with` já faz isso pra você.